# running thread at the same time swing gui is running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass extends Observable implements Runnable
{
...
}
```

I have to exceute this thread in background during swing gui running.which could be the best solution?
If I don't make a mistake, I can't use `SwingWorker`.right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SwingWorker` is made specifically for that purpose. Go ahead and use it, it will work. Read its documentation first.

If you want to use the class you already have, you can do that too. Just do this:

`new Thread (new MyClass ()).start ();`.

Comment: But I don't understand how use swing worked...my class has already a superclass and to use swingworker I have to extend

Comment: @Mazzy Well in that case, use the second approach in my answer. And yes, you must make sure not to access any GUI stuff from that thread, everything Swing-related MUST be executed on the EDT. You can use `invokeLater`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

**SwingWorker is introduced in Java for the purpose of Synchronizing the UI thread work and Non-UI thread work, as Doing Non-UI work on UI thread will make the GUI less responsive...**
Make sure only your GUI code runs in Event Dispatcher Thread.

As **in Android we have AsyncTask<>** for this purpose...